# The meaning of “Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an.”

Tags: meaning, idiom

What is the meaning of the following sentence and in what situations it is used?

> Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an.

Comment: Can you provide context? It is ambiguous.

Comment: I tried switching on the light, it stayed dark. Try again! **switch** *light stays out*  Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Das geht nicht an

is colloquial German (and thus probably not to be found in a dictionary) for

> That is a no-go
>
> That doesn't work

Or maybe even

> That is not acceptable

Or everything in a wider sense of "not possible", "not allowed", "not acceptable", "not respectable", with some unspoken morality of "that's bad manners"/"you just don't do that"

Some example would be

> Es geht nun wirklich nicht an, dass die Bahn schon wieder die Fahrpreise erhöht
>
> Es geht ja gar nicht an, dass in unsrer Firma Männer und Frauen dieselbe Toilette benutzen müssen
>
> Die Tochter der Nachbarn habe ich gestern Nacht um eins noch in der Stadt gesehen - Das geht ja nun wirklich nicht an, dass junge Mädchen so spät noch alleine unterwegs sind.

The expression is specific to the northern half of Germany, nobody in the south would say it like that.

Comment: Is it really colloquial? We have exactly the same expression in Swedish, borrowed from lower German long a go, probably in the 16th cy ("Det går inte an"), which is here a rather elevated style, not colloquial at all.

Comment: @Beta Duden does list it and does actually *not* list it as colloquial. So I probably cannot insist on it. Where I live, the expression is entirely uncommon, not even in "hochdeutsch" conversations, though, so I would tag it as colloquial, even maybe dialect (Hamburg or thereabouts, locals might know better)

Comment: @Beta Well, if someone said to me "Das geht wirklich nicht an", I would understand that I cannot turn/switch it on. This is standard German. However, in the sense as tofro answered the question, to me it's plainly wrong. It sounds totally weird. I would probably get the meaning from context; but I can't remember having heard that before. As such, it must be colloquial and even restricted to some dialects / idolects.

Comment: I've never heard this around Bremen

Comment: Hier auch (Bedeutung 5): http://www.dwds.de/wb/angehen

Comment: @Em1 I believe your conclusion about the expressions colloquilaty is not logic, at least not for me. In my view, there is a definite difference between "regional" and "colloquial". Regional Hochsprache in one region may not be immediate natural to a speaker from another region, but still not Umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Hast Du eine Beispiel, wo es im Sinne von "that doesn't work" verwendet wird. In diesem Sinne habe ich es noch nie gehört. Als vorwurfsvollen Tadel dagegen hört man es in Berlin oft.

Comment: *Es geht nicht an, dass man uns zwingt, das Projekt in 3 Wochen durchzuziehen.* - grenzwertig, ob das als "doesn't work" durchgeht...

Comment: @tofro: Nein, das geht nicht durch. :)  Übrigens musst Du mich direkt adressieren, damit ich ein Bummerl kriege, weil es schon mehr als einen Kommentator gibt. Ich dagegen darf darauf verzichten, weil ich unter Deiner Antwort kommentiere, nicht (nur) auf einen Kommentar reagiere.

Comment: »Das geht nicht an« klingt nicht umgangssprachlich sondern antiquiert, zumindest nach meinem Sprachgefühl. Ein mir bekannter Sprachwissenschaftler (der auf seine Wortwahl achtet und einen recht eigentümlichen, bildungsbürgerlichen Schreib- und Sprachstil hat, den ich nicht uneingeschränkt gut finde) verwendet diesen Ausdruck scherzhaft altertümelnd.

Comment: @Beta: I think it is used in Dutch too: "het gaat niet aan (dat)" http://context.reverso.net/vertaling/nederlands-engels/het+gaat+niet+aan+dat. No idea if we have it from German.

Comment: Ich stimme user unknowns Kommentar vom 30.9. zu, sowohl was den Teil "oft vorwurfsvoll zu hören" angeht als auch die Skepsis bezüglich der Verwendung im Sinne von "doesn't work"

Answer (score 3):

Well I actually come from northern germany and we do not use the phrase this way.

> - Das kann (ja) wirklich nicht angehen.
> - Das gibt es (ja) nicht.
> - Das kann (ja) nicht sein.

Those are some examples which actually all mean the same. Notice that you can drop *ja* but it is mostly used to empower to show that you are really upset. Also you will never split *angehen* into *geht ... an*.

Comment: or "Das kann (es) (ja(wohl)) nicht sein."

Answer (score 1):

No, that couldn't be done.

Well it can mean "No, you can't do that" also or "I would not do that".

Comment: "Es geht nicht an, dass Franz glaubt, die Tischrede halten zu dürfen! (Weil ich sie zu halten auserwählt bin)." Neither is it impossible, nor is the person spoken to neccessarily the one, which shouldn't act (while acting isn''t neccessarily involved), nor needs the same rule to apply for the speaker. "Es  geht doch nicht an, dass es am Wochenende schon wieder regnet!" Natürlich kann es sein - sonst wäre kein Lamento nötig. Der Angesprochene regnet nicht. Man selbst könnte auch gar nicht regnen(, sofern es keine fiktionale, psychedelische Story von 2 sprechenden Wolken ist).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence expresses strong disfavor, often a violation of rules, often informal ones.

It can be used to show discomfort with peoples actions, but is used for unlucky incidents as well:

> »Ich bin wieder beim Schwarzfahren erwischt worden – das dritte Mal diese Woche!«
>   »Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an.«
>
> »Die Bedienung hat mir einen Kaffee gebracht, der nur noch lauwarm war!«
>   »Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an.«
>
> »Gehen wir heute wieder ins Freibad?«
>   »Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an! Es ist doch nur noch 15 Grad draußen!«
>
> »Es geht doch nicht an, dass schon wieder der Blitz eingeschlagen hat!«
>   »Nein, das geht wirklich nicht an!«

I disagree with tofro’s “That doesn't work”. It’s not about whether a situation is possible, but whether it is very unpleasant. It’s often the attempt to deny the reality.

Answer (score 0):

"Das geht nicht an” perhaps translates best into *British* English as "That is *not on.*"

An American might say, "That is a *non-starter*," or a *no-go*."

The "nein," and "wirklich" are there for emphasis. The context is that the idea is *dead in the water*, or even *born dead*.

Comment: Meine Erfahrung ist, dass die Phrase v.a. verwendet wird um zu lamentieren, nachdem die Sache, die nicht angeht, längst passiert ist, so dass non-starter (kenne ich aber wiederum nicht) nicht überzeugend klingt.